# Why can't I resolve Omdb promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api, omdbapi

I was learning making api calls. So I started using OMDB api to get movie information.

```js
fetch(http: //www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=f69f0628&s=batman )
    .then((success) => {
      success.json()
    })
    .then((movies) => {
      console.log(movies)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
```

The above code gives me the error in firefox

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

When I do this (added single quotes to the url) :

```js
fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=f69f0628&s=batman')
  .then((success) => {
    success.json()
  })
  .then((movies) => {
    console.log(movies)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

It gives the console log:

```
undefined
```

Comment: `.then((success) =>{ success.json() } )` should be `.then((success) =>{ return success.json() } )` or `.then((success) => success.json() )` - see arrow function [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to understand

Comment: [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) requires you to pass resource as  a string or request object, why would you want to do it otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at line `.then((success) =>{ success.json() } )`

it should be `.then((success) => success.json() )` without `{ }`

Or `.then((success) =>{ return success.json() } )`

You can find detail of arrow function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax)

```js
fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=f69f0628&s=batman')
  .then((success) => success.json())
  .then((movies) => {
    console.log(movies)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```